# Package installation from git in SWI prolog

Tags: installation, prolog, package, swi-prolog

I am attempting to install library(reif) on Ubuntu 20.04 from git using the pack_install/1 predicate of SWI prolog. Here is the output.

```
% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
Install reif@1.0.0 from GIT at https://github.com/meditans/reif.git Y/n? 
ERROR: Could not find executable file "git" in $PATH
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [19] throw(error(existence_error(source_sink,...),_58814))
ERROR:   [15] process:process_create(path(git),[clone,'https://github.com/meditans/reif.git'|...],[stdout(...),...|...]) at /snap/swi-prolog/48/usr/lib/swipl/library/process.pl:270
ERROR:   [14] build_tools:run_process(path(git),[clone,'https://github.com/meditans/reif.git'|...],[]) at /snap/swi-prolog/48/usr/lib/swipl/library/build/tools.pl:528
ERROR:   [13] prolog_pack:pack_install_from_url(https,'https://github.com/meditans/reif.git','/home/audun/snap/swi-prolog/48/.local/share/swi-prolog/pack',reif,[git(true),...|...]) at /snap/swi-prolog/48/usr/lib/swipl/library/prolog_pack.pl:993
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /snap/swi-prolog/48/usr/lib/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1162
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

The git command is in my path, so Im stuck. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Audun

Comment: Better get [the source](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/). In the meantime, it's v3 for reif.

Comment: And, for best results, rather use SICStus or Scryer.

Comment: @false Why don't you publish a Git version? I know it is your code and you have the freedom to choose but with it not being on Git it is like saying I don't want it to be found.

Comment: Since the code at http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl does not contain a copyright, is it free to use as one sees fit or is there a copyright on the site that I missed?

Comment: Thank you for all help. Downloading source and switching to SICStus. Scryer looks good but does it have an API in a scripting language for meta-management ?